# How to retrieve different object types from IQueryable

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, ado.net, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework 5 code first. I have the following query that returns 2 different objects:

```
var query = (from s in DatabaseContext.Servers
             join c in DatabaseContext.CommandExecutionServers on s.Domain equals c.Domain
             where s.Id == serverId && c.Active == active
             select new { s, c });
```

s is a `Server class` and c is a `CEServer class`.

How do I retrieve the s and c objects from query because I need to work with them.  I need something like:

```
Server server = s;  // first check for nulls and
server.CEServer = c;  // check for nulls as well
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you sure that you will get only and exact one pair, you can use this:

```
Server server = query.Single().s;  // first check for nulls and
server.CEServer = query.Single().c;
```

if no, you will get **exception**.

Comment: Thanks. How would one check if s and c are null?

Comment: The question is not clear. Do you want to check when both `s` and `c` are `null`?

Comment: Yes. They might nor always contain data. So if s is null and you do `query.Single().s` will it throw an exception?

Comment: No, if `s` is `null` you will get `null` in `server`. It is easy to check.

Comment: Ok that I can do, was just wondering what would happen if s is null and you try to do query.Single().

Comment: Remember, the `Single` will throw the exception if not exact one element in the `query`.

Answer (score 1):

Since your query returns a sequence of objects of *anonymous* class, you can enumerate your query, and access `s` and `c` from each returned row, like this:

```
foreach (var row in query) {
    Server s = row.s;
    // Check the server...
    CEServer c = row.c;
    // Use CEServer...
}
```